# Dynamically query an object set in EF using LambdaExpression

Tags: c#, .net, linq, entity-framework, entity-framework-4

I am trying to dynamically query Entity Framework, so I'm using the Expression class to put together a LambdaExpression that will be queried against an object set.  If I have a reference to LambdaExpression, where I don't have an explicit function defined, is it possible to query against an objectset this way, or is it required to have a generic expression defined (using `Expression.Lambda<..>`)?

Thanks.

Comment: Can you give us a sample of the code you want to use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what I was looking to do:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb882637.aspx

Using this, I was able to build a lambda expression against an object set dynamically.  Worked very well.

Answer (score 0):

Check out [Dynamic Linq](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2008/01/07/dynamic-linq-part-1-using-the-linq-dynamic-query-library.aspx). Basically you can use strings in place of LINQ expressions until you want to use them. Sounds like it might be what you want.